# RxJava timeout without unsubscribing from source

Tags: operators, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm subscribing to hot observable, and then applying `timeout` operator to it, however I do not want to unsubscribe when `TimeoutException` is thrown, only produce special item (I know that source will eventually emit new items). How can I achieve that?

I'm trying to combine timeout with `onErrorReturn` but again this causes `onComplete` call on the subscriber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publish, timeout and retry (adapted from [my older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31121395/61158)):

```
Observable<Long> source =
    Observable.just(100L, 200L, 500L, 1000L, 5000L, 5500L, 6000L)
    .flatMap(v -> Observable.timer(v, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).map(a -> v));

source.publish(co -> 
    co.timeout(750, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 
         Observable.just(-1L)
         .concatWith(Observable.error(new RuntimeException()))
    )
    .retry()
 ).blockingForEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. In my case the source is already hot so, no need to use publish. What I was missing is the combination of concatWith() and retry() which is the key I think.